# Devise registration error messages cleared or reset after validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a problem with error messages using devise registration.  In my custom devise controller, I have the create method where I would return the resource on validation failure.  For some reason, resource.errors are cleared when sign up page is rendered.  Has anyone encountered this problem?  I am using dm-devise 2.1.0

Here is my code if it helps:

```
class UserDevise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController  
  def create
    begin
      build_resource
      ....    
    rescue DataMapper::SaveFailureError => e
      resource = e.resource
      clean_up_passwords(resource)  
      respond_with resource
    end    
  end
end
```

EDIT: Here is the code for clean_up_passwords as requested (they are defined by Devise):

```
def clean_up_passwords(object)
  object.clean_up_passwords if object.respond_to?(:clean_up_passwords)
end

def clean_up_passwords
  self.password = self.password_confirmation = nil
end
```

EDIT2: Here is the view code for the signup page:

```
<div class="account-container">
<div class="content clearfix">
  <%= simple_form_for resource, :html => {:class => 'form-vertical'}, :url => registration_path(resource_name) do |f| %>
  <h1>Create Account</h1>
  <div class="login-fields">
     <p>Please provide the following info:</p>
     <%= f.input :name, :placeholder => "Full Name", :input_html=>{:class => "login username-field"} %>
     <%= f.input :email, :placeholder => "Email Address", :input_html=>{:class => "login username-field"} %>
     <%= f.input :password, :placeholder => "Password", :input_html=>{:class => "login password-field"} %>
     <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Password Confirmation", :input_html=>{:class => "login password-field"} %>
  </div>    
  <div class="login-actions">
     <%= f.button :submit, "Sign Up", :class => 'button btn  btn-warning btn-large' %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you check to see if resource contains the errors prior to the call to clean_up_passwords?  Also, can you add the code for clean_up_passwords to the question?

Comment: Yes..the resource contains the errors after calling clean_up_passwords and up until respond_with is called.  Somehow, respond_with cleared the errors :(

Comment: Can you also post up the view code for your sign up page?

Comment: Just added the view code as requested.  I don't see any inline validation errors when the page is rendered after validation.  I also put in code in the view (not as part of this posting) to display resource.errors and it is empty.